# Get the json object count inside the json array

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

From the below json Response the view array contains more than one objects.
Using rest assured how can i iterate json objects inside the view array

code used

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().when().get(getURL);
  ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> jsonList = response.jsonPath().get("views");
  jsonList.size();
  //It returns size 1


[{
        gameIfd: 2018916,
        gameIdGlobal: 1948141,
        views: [{
                name: "Preview",
                displayOrder: 1,
                groups: [],
                actions: [],
                localizedName: {}
            },{
                name: "Thumbnail",
                displayOrder: 2,
                groups: [],
                actions: [],
                localizedName: {}
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Using Jackson converter you can convert the json into pojo and then you can iterate over that. I am not sure about rest assured.

Comment: your json is incorrect

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ your json is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I found this way

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().when().get(getURL);
JsonPath pathResponse = response.jsonPath();
List<String> key = pathResponse.getList("views[0]");

  System.out.println(key.size()); //Whcih prints the jsonobjects inside views array
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main JSON response is a list. So when you call `response.jsonPath().get("views")` it gives you the list of all `views` from all objects in the main list. Instead of assigning to `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>` you should assign it to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>>` as follows:

```
     ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>> jsonList = 
                                       response.jsonPath().get("views");
```

Then you can get the **first** object's `views` list as:

```
jsonList.get(0).size()
```

And `response.jsonPath().get("views[0]")` also gives you the first object's `views` list.